Azure: Subscribing to an external MQTT Broker
One of our customers has MQTT brokers with https://www.emqx.com/  which we need to consume in Azure.
Previously we had used Azure Functions with an MQTT trigger on (https://github.com/keesschollaart81/CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt)
However, this library is now pretty old and we need to move to .net 8. The Library looks like it needs a lot of work to update.
So the 3 possibilities I am looking at are:

See if Azure has another way to subscribe to an external MQTT Broker.  Event Grid doesn't seem to support this, nor IOT hub
The Brokers also support Websockets, can Azure subscribe to that?  Doesn't really fit the serverless model, would it have to a be a VM?
Bridge the brokers in Emqx to link with Event Grid or IOT Hub

Any advice on this would be epic,

There is no built-in an azure service for your solution, so from the architecture point of view, I do recommend update this MQTT Trigger function using the latest MQTTnet library.
This custom azure MQTT Trigger function will be simplified a "bridge between the topics" and also a publishing on the topic of the MQTT broker included the AEG MQTT Broker.
